# How do I create a claims aware identity/token

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

I'm trying to hand implement a federated token service.

The authentication mechanism that we're using is actually an OAuth provider, so we need our FP to accept the OAuth access token and use and transform it in to a claims aware identity. Basically this:

- FP receives a token and verifies that it is from a trusted source (e.g. In-house, Google, Facebook, etc)
- FP fires a factory that figures out where to get it's transformation logic from based on the incoming token format and the requested application ID
- FP uses the found logic to contact the application and receives a list of rights for the user
- FP generates a token and returns it to the client
- Client uses token to make requests against the application.
- Application verifies the token is from a trusted source and continues to the operation
- Operation checks to see if the requested resource is authorized within the claims of the token and decides whether to complete or deny the operation.

[image]

I'm having trouble actually figuring out how to generate the token (once I get the list of rights, what do I do with them? How do I generate a string token, etc). Most resources on the net are wrapped around the use of active directory, which is not what we're using. So what I need to figure out is how to generate the token that the client will be able to use and how to consume that token in the application. Any resources would be helpful. I feel like there's a part of the framework that should handle this automatically, but I'm just not seeing it.